# Curl Request not working on new sever

Tags: magento, curl

Recently we have moved our website on new server and after that curl requests has stopped working. Our website is on Magento and we are using a plugin which sends request to a webservice using curl.

This code is working on local system and also in old server but on new server curl send the blank response.

I have also print the curl_error output and it is saying "couldn't connect to host". Please let me know if anyone has face this same issue.

Comment: The curl request code -  $tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL,$auth_query);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT, 9001);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept:application/xml'));   
$response = curl_exec($tuCurl);   
$response1 = curl_getinfo( $tuCurl );`

Comment: "couldn't connect to host" means exactly that. The TCP handshake cannot be performed. You connect to the wrong IP/port or something prevents it from working.

Comment: In webservice url, we are using 9001 port. But this is working for other clients and also for this client on old server.

Comment: Then you better figure out why it doesn't work on this...

Comment: Now we are getting another error NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified). Could you please let me know how can I resolve this

Comment: ... then you got passed the problem in this question and you're now asking a different question!

Answer (score 0):

is very explicit ... it means Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

The following code would work on any system:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://google.com");    // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data);
```

If you can not see google page then .. your URL is wrong or you have some firewall or restriction issue.

Comment: Your code is working fine. And that error is coming because of the port which we are using in api url. We have allowed that port but now we are getting another error NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified). Could you please let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this error NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)?